# Service undefined when injected into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have a controller that I have injected a factory into but it comes back as undefined when I call a method on that factory. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Factory:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    // Declare factory and add it 'HomeAutomation' namespace.
    angular.module('HomeAutomation').factory('AuthenticationService', ['$http','$localStorage', '$window', function($http, $localStorage, $window){
    var service = {};


    service.login = Login;
    service.logout = Logout;
    service.parseJWT = parseJWT;
    service.loginStatus = loginStatus;

    return service;


    function Login(email, password, callback){
        $http.post('api/user/login', {email: email, password: password})
            .success(function(res){
                // Login successful if there is a token in the response.
                if(res.token){
                    // store username and token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    $localStorage.currentUser = { email: email, token: res.token };

                    // add jwt token to auth header for all requests made by the $http service
                    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + res.token;

                    callback(true);
                }else{
                    callback(res);
                }
            }).error(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    function Logout(){
        $localStorage.currrntUser
    }

    function parseJWT(token){
        var base64URL, base64;

        base64URL = token.split('.')[1];
        base64 = base64URL.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');

        console.log(JSON.parse($window.atob(base64)));
    }

    function loginStatus(){
        if($localStorage.currentUser){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}]);}());
```

Controller:

```
(function(){
angular.module('HomeAutomation')
    .controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', function($scope, $location, $localStorage, AuthenticationService){
        $scope.isLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.logout();

        $scope.logUserIn = function(){
            AuthenticationService.login($scope.login.email, $scope.login.password, function(result){
                if(result === true){
                    $location.path('/');
                }else{
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.logUserOut = function(){
            AuthenticationService.logOut();
        }
    }]);}());
```

This is the line that is causing the err:

```
$scope.isLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.logout();
```

Apparently "AuthenticationService" is undefined. Not sure why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up with depedency sequence, you need to remove `$localStorage` from controller factory function since `$localStorage` isn't use anywhere in controller & haven't injected in DI array.

```
.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', 
    function($scope, $location, AuthenticationService){
                //^^^^^^^^^^removed $localStorage dependency from here
```

> **NOTE:** Always make sure when you inject any dependency in DI array, they should used in same sequence in controller function

Answer (score 0):

The injection is not good :

```
.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', function($scope, $location, $localStorage, AuthenticationService){
```

Try with this :

```
.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', '$localStorage', 'AuthenticationService', function($scope, $location, $localStorage, AuthenticationService){
```

I don't know which builder you use, but for example with `Gulp`, you can use `gulp-ng-annotate` that will do the job for you so that you can only write :

```
.controller('loginController', function($scope, $location, $localStorage, AuthenticationService){
```

without the array. The `ng-annotate` will take care of the rest.

Comment: I do use gulp. I will try that out. Thanks.